# Choose specific url without writing a lot of if statement

Tags: ios, swift

I'm  working on an horoscope application now I have a problem after user selected is zodiac how can I know what php url to show him for example:

there is 12 zodiac's so how can I give him his horoscope for this url for example

NSURL: "blablabla_horscope.com/libra/today_horoscope"

I mean I don't want to write in Xcode twelve options of url, and start making if statements for example "*if this user and then use here is NSUserDefaults with his choosed zodiac*"
since then I will have to start making a list of a lot of if statement and it will make my app work slow and it's a bad idea so I have thinking about making some kinda of php file, that will handle all that after the user registered in the background but where to start for that?

I'm currently working on Swift, core-data, php.

```
let urlString = "http://www.blablabla/?sign=libra&time=today"
    let url = NSURL (string: urlString)
    let dataURL = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url!, options: [])
     let result: String = String(data: dataURL!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    print("the result is %@", result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your constant for the sign type prior to setting your urlString.

```
let sign = "libra"
or
let sign = "cancer"
etc...
```

and then you can:

```
let urlString = "http://www.blablabla/?sign=\(sign)&time=today"
```

Late